# Insert foreign key into table with SQL query using C#

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys, sqlcommand

I have a database with 3 tables `Identification`, `Identification_group` and `Group`.

The `Identification_group` table has 2 foreign key columns, `Identificaiton_id` and `Group_id`.

In my form you can select the Group Number and it returns the right Group_id to the `Identification_group` table.

Is it possible to write a SQL query that uses the last `Identification_id` and the `Group_id` (from the selection field in my form) and writes this to the `Identification_group` table?

```
string sqlquery1 = "Insert into [dbo].[identification_group] (fk_group_id,fk_identification_id values (@fk_group_id,@fk_identification_id;";
            SqlCommand schreiben = new SqlCommand(sqlquery1, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_identification_id", intidentification_id);
            schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_group_id", Wil_Jls_idComboBox.SelectedValue);
schreiben.CommandText = sqlquery;
schreiben.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, first time posting here.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you just need to execute the command with  schreiben.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Forgot to add it, updatet my Code now.
The line making Problems is "schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_identification_id", intidentification_id);"  
I think i need to use something like "lastSelectedId" but i can´t seem to make it work.

Comment: Remove the `@` symbol from `schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_identification_id", intidentification_id);` - you only need the `@` symbol in the SQL query statement, not in the actual C# code. Also you have no closing brackets in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

You have an issue with your SQL statement whereby you did not close the brackets. Also, you only need the `@` symbol in the SQL statement, and not in the C# code.

```
// Create the query
string query = "Insert into [identification_group] (fk_group_id, fk_identification_id) values (@fk_group_id, @fk_identification_id)";

// Create the SQL command
SqlCommand schreiben = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

// Open the SQL connection
myConnection.Open();

// Bind the parameters
schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("fk_identification_id", intidentification_id);
schreiben.Parameters.AddWithValue("fk_group_id", Wil_Jls_idComboBox.SelectedValue);

// Bind the command
schreiben.CommandText = query;

// Execute the command
schreiben.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Close the connection
myConnection.Close();
```